# Enforce java 8 conventions using checkStyle

Tags: java, java-8, checkstyle

I'm looking to enforce some best practices for Java 8 using checkStyle, some examples include:

1. Don't nest optionals
2. Limit lambdas to x lines if it's in the middle of stream transformations
3. General warning against parallel stream

Based on my research, I can see that checkStyle supports java 8, but nothing specific to enforcing standards on features.

Is this something that's available?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

If checkstyle supports it out of the box, it'll be listed among [the standard checks that checkstyle comes with](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/checks.html) (I didn't see any when I glanced over it, unfortunately).  If it's not in that list, I would then start looking at third party checkstyle libraries (such as [SevNTU Checkstyle](http://sevntu-checkstyle.github.io/sevntu.checkstyle/), [Checkstyle Addons](http://checkstyle-addons.thomasjensen.com/), and [CS-Contrib](http://unkrig.de/w/Cs-contrib.unkrig.de) among them) to see if you can find checks that satisfy your needs.  If you are still unable to find anything, you might have to [implement the checks yourself](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html). If you do, you might want to consider [contributing](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/contributing.html) them to the community, winning the eternal gratitude of checkstyle users around the world.